# How much bandwith my PHP script will require?

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting, bandwidth

I have a PHP page that will be called by a JS Userscript everytime the user refresh our forum thread list page (I'm not the forum's owner). 
This page will show a JSON object generated from a 4 fields DB, containing blacklisted usernames and messages, because the forum is getting flooded by some bots and forum developpers have no idea how to fix their website vulnerabilites.

The userscript may be used by 900-1000 users, maybe up 200 at a time.

And I have another PHP script that has to be executed every minute to access 5 most recent threads, and for each message of the thread, search through the forum to check if the message has already been post.

So for 5 topics * 8 messages (in average) every 60 sec I use :

`file_get_contents('http://forum.com/q?"MESSAGE"&type=searchbymessage')`

If the same message has already been posted by the same user more than 3 times on 3 different threads within 5 minutes, the script adds his username to the DB in order to blacklist him.

Initially I wanted to use a free domain name and the free webhosting service [000webhost](https://000webhost.com), but I wonder if the bandwith will be enough to handle that? And if 100 users call the first PHP page with the JSON object within a minute, it will imply to connect to the DB 100 times within a minute... Should I go for an paid hosting service or a VPS? Which ones would be the less expensive for my needs? Should I use a flat txt as a DB?

According to 000webhost, the website could handle up to 400 rpm and 10 000 mb monthly bandwith [000webhost limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMX7S.png)

Comment: 1. To check the bandwith (the amount of data) your page takes, just load the page with the network tab in your browsers developer console open and check. 2. Why do you check the messages with `file_get_contents()`? Check directly in the DB instead and it will take zero bandwith. We can't answer what's enough, since we have _no clue_ about the amount of data your site takes. It's all a cumulation of all the images/scripts etc.

Comment: >1.

Ok I will try that then once the script is finished.

>2. 

Because as I said the forum I'm scanning with my PHP script is not mine

Comment: Honestly, the best way to fix the problem is to fix the problem from within the forum app itself. Scraping the forum from the 'outside' to check for spammers is never going to be efficient. That said...I'd reduce the frequency of your checks to the minimum tolerable (one pass every 15 minutes?). If the forum has a plain text mode I would use that before I would choose to use the same endpoints it serves to normal users.

Comment: You should be able to run your app for a while on your own machine to directly measure the amount of data that scraping the forum uses. Serving your JSON is another matter (e.g. how frequently can your endpoint be called? Consider a rate limit.)